# typeahead: selected value clipped after last matched letter

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

strange problem with typeahead.

Typing, for example, "W" and then selecting this value:
[image]

Produces this:

[image]

When I do this in the autocomplete select function:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var professionName = ui.item.label;
    console.log(professionName);
}
```

Bizarre - the item label consists only of the text FOLLOWING the highlighted letter.

Thoughts?

Thanks !!

[EDIT]

Here's the HTML & javascript, as requested. (Typeahead is version 0.12.2)

```
    <div class="span6 float_r">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="drpProfession">Profession/Occupation:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="drpProfession" name="drpProfession" value="<?=$professionCurrentLabel;?>" placeholder="Search for profession"><a href="#" class="small" onclick="javascript: $('#drpProfession').val('');; $('#drpProfessionID').val('');">clear</a>
                <input type="hidden" id="drpProfessionID" name="drpProfessionID" value="<?=$professionCurrentId;?>">
            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var professionLabelFieldID = 'drpProfession';
    var professionIdFieldID = 'drpProfessionID';
    var professionsValues = <?=$optionsProfessionValues?>;
    var professionsLabels = <?=$optionsProfessionLabels?>;
    prepProfessionAutocomplete(professionsValues, professionsLabels, professionLabelFieldID, professionIdFieldID);

function prepProfessionAutocomplete (professionsValues, professionsLabels, professionLabelFieldID, professionIdFieldID) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#'+professionLabelFieldID).autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: professionsLabels,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var professionName = ui.item.label;
                var professionID = 0;
                var professionValueIndex = professionsLabels.indexOf(professionName);
                var professionDbID = professionsValues[professionValueIndex];
                if (professionName.length > 0 && professionDbID > 0) {
                    professionID = professionDbID;
                }
                $('#'+professionIdFieldID).val(professionID);
                console.log(professionName);
                return true;
            }
        }).keyup(function() {
            // Upper case values in case user is entering new ones
            this.value = ucwords(this.value);
        });
   });
   $('#'+professionLabelFieldID).change(function() {
      if ($('#'+professionLabelFieldID).val() == '') {
          // user "deleted" profession. Capture it
          $('#'+professionIdFieldID).val('');
      }
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can post `html` , `js` ,  `source` of typeahead ?

Answer (score 0):

One simple change...

from this:

```
var professionName = ui.item.label;
```

to this:

```
var professionName = ui.item.value;
```

I started out with bootstrap autocomplete, where "label" worked, but switched to typeahead, which must have broken it. All set now!